# Is a final static class method possible?

Tags: php, class, inheritance, static

I need a class to inherit another class. I have a static function `_init()` in the base class, and I don't want that method to be inherited in the derived class. I tried the `final` keyword but it's not working. What should I do?

Comment: If you need an initialization of your code you probably better use objects.

Comment: First of all, why do you not want the base class to have access to this method?  If you don't want the derived class to have access to it, make it private.  Second option is overriding it in the derived class.

Comment: I want the base class to access that method _init() but not the derived class!

Comment: I removed the OOP tag because you are doing class based programming which is basically just procedural programming with classes.

Comment: +1 to Zoidberg. The immediate solution to this problem is to make the method private.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're misunderstanding what final means.

One of the foundation principles of OOP is that if a class is a subclass of another class, then that class gets all the functionality of the class it inherits from.  You can't inherit just some of the superclass functionality, it's all or nothing.

The reason for this is a bit tricky to get to grips with but once you do, you'll realise that it makes sense.  Namely, if a piece of code is able to process items of a particular class, then it must also be able to process any subclass of the item as well.  If a subclass didn't have all the functionality of its superclass, you couldn't do that.

For example, imagine you have a class that defines interfacing with a payment gateway.  As all payment gateways are different, you couldn't (or at least shouldn't) implement a single class that can interface with any of the payment gateways that are available.  But in general, payment gateways work in the same basic way.  A request is sent, including a user's credit card details and amount you want to debit from the card.  The payment gateway responds with a message saying whether payment was authorized or not.

You'd implement that kind of functionality with an abstract superclass that defines how you interface with payment gateways in general, then you'd create a subclass for each payment gateway you want to use (paypal, sagepay, whatever).

As all these subclasses inherit from the same base class, you can be certain that they all implement certain methods, and you can send messages to those methods without worry.  As long as the payment class you're dealing with is a subclass of your abstract payment class, then everything should work.

If one of the subclasses was able to not implement something from the abstract superclass, then you couldn't be sure that sending a particular message to a subclass would work, or throw an exception.  This would make inheritance rather pointless.

Final in PHP (and indeed most OOP languages that implement it or similar concepts) means "This is the final implementation of this method.  If a programmer subclasses me, then he can't replace my final methods with his own implementation".  It doesn't mean that the methods will not be available in the subclass, just that you can't change them.

If you really must remove functionality from a subclass, you can do it by overriding the superclass method and replacing it with an empty method (one that does nothing).  But don't do that, as it will cause problems of the type discussed above.

Generally, if you run into situations where you have functionality in a superclass that you don't need in a subclass, it's a code smell that's telling you that you might need to rethink your design.

Answer (score 3):

You are doing it the wrong way.

Just the fact that you want the extended class to **not** have a method, means you are violating [Liskov's substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) .. if reading is hard: here is **[a picture](https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/files/2011/03/LiskovSubtitutionPrinciple_52BB5162.jpg)** explaining it.

If you have a situation, when you have to perform some sort of "work" on object before you *release it* into the application, then you should use a Factory/Builder for it.

```
class FooBuilder
{
   public function create( $external_condition )
   {
      $object = new Foo;
      if ( $external_condition->has_happened() )
      {
         $object->set_condition( $external_condition );
      }else{
         $object->do_something_else();
      }
      return $object;
   }
}
```

Now you always make instances of `Foo` class through `FooBuilder`, ad when you extend `Foo`, it does not have any useless methods.

Additionally, i would argue that static methods in classes are a sign of procedural programing. And static variables are nothing else but global variables wrapped in namespace masquerading as class.

Comment: I Got your point! about the Liskov substitution principle.. But how could i get the scenario in action! is there any principle am missing out?? is there any way?

Comment: @TirthBodawala , which is the scenario you are talking about ?

Answer (score 3):

Static means one per class, not one for each object no matter how many instance of a class might exist. This means that you can use them without creating an instance of a class.Static methods are implicitly final, because overriding is done based on the type of the object, and static methods are attached to a class, not an object. A static method in a superclass can be shadowed by another static method in a subclass, as long as the original method was not declared final. However, you can't override a static method with a nonstatic method. In other words, you can't change a static method into an instance method in a subclass.

A final class can't be extended ie., final class may not be subclassed. A final method can't be overridden when its class is inherited. You can't change value of a final variable (is a constant).

Answer (score 2):

In POO, if a class B inherits another class A, the class B will contain all the methods from class A, this is the foundation of POO heritage. So `I don't want that method to be inherited in the derived class` make no sense here. You should look at another mechanism to do that.

Also, is `most` cases, such situation (where you don't want the derived class inherits a method) is a sign that your derived class should not inherit at all, and where you should use another system.

Comment: Can you suggest one?? I am using singleton structure for accessing the class and initializing it once only!

Comment: It highly depends on what you want to do, and why you want it for.

Comment: I want the base class to be initialized only once.. and the derived not to posses that _init() method.. can i do that? because there are critical data when base class calls the _init() static function.

Comment: well, if your class is a singleton, you can put the __init call in the constructor (not the good way if your __init function is doing a lot of things). Or, you can add an attribute which will flag if the __init method has been called (not the good way too). What do you want exactly ? Do you want the __init method be called only once or do you want the __init method be callable only form the parent class ? In the first case, the method provided by tereško is a solution.

Comment: I am extremely delighted that u got my point.. i want both!!! I want that the _init() function can only be called once by the parent class!

Comment: Well, if the purpose of the __init method is actually to init the object, you could put that stuff into the constructor of the parent class. Derived class couldn't call it directly I think (to be verified). But... here is a question, why do you want BOTH inheritance and singleton ? How many classes will be derived from the base class ? If one, why are you doing a derived class ? If more than one, how will you handle the singleton pattern ? Singleton means ONE (in most cases) but you've more than one derived classes...

Answer (score 1):

Check this example:

```
class foo
{
  private static $stuff = array('key1' => 1, 'key2' => 2);

  public final static function getstuff()
  {
   return self::$stuff;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would agree with pomeh on OOP in PHP and I would also want to add that the FINAL keyword when used with a method actually means that the method cannot be overridden. The method will be inherited though.